# Harmonic complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone help me with this question?

Show that a $C^2$ function, $f:U\longrightarrow \mathbb C$, is harmonic iff $\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}\equiv0$.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the _definitions_ of $\partial f\partial z$ and $\partial f/\partial\overline z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
$$
we get that when operating on $C^2$ functions (where we have [the Equality of Mixed Partials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives)),
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}
&=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\\[6pt]
&=\Delta
\end{align}$$